# UIView doesn't move in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am investigating this problem for three days without much result.

According to what I found on Stackoverflow, I should set the content size bigger than my actual content, which I have done:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 700);
```

I also have added Autolayout `constraints` for each item in the scrollview container, to stick to the superview (scrollview) and to each other.

However there is no joy. I have uploaded this [example](https://github.com/houmie/iOSscrollView) on Github.

What am I missing please?
Thanks

Comment: Check this video for autolayout on Scrollview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI

Comment: make constraint on Container view's height  "Equal height to Scrollview" and set it priority to low. and set its constraints for leading, trailing, top and bottom w.r.t scrollview and then add content in this container view

Comment: @AsadullahAli  Thank you for this fantastic insight.  Applying your solution helped me to show the entire content in the scrollview.

Comment: @AsadullahAli I just discovered that even though your solution works, it doesn't allow the scrolling to be smooth.  It either is on top or jumps to bottom. (Get latest for my example please)  I can't scroll in between.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: One suggestion for you try to resize your views with constraints try less use of mouse or track pad. It ll help manage your constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a constraint wrong.

[image]

That bottom constraint should be set to 0 (it's -138). Then all should work. I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayouts, the `contentSize` property of `UIScrollView` doesn't work anymore. You will have to establish scrollview intrinsic size using Autolayout constraints.

You could check this tutorial about ScrollViews and Autolayouts for more info:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/